# Table Parsing using selenium webdriver php?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

Hello Friends,
              I want to fetch all table information which is contained in td section.
I have tried this code:

```
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; // this is the default
$capabilities = array(WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'firefox');
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities,1000);

 $results = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('table #listbody tr'));

 for($i=0;$i<count($results);$i++)
 {
   echo $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::className('rank'))->getext();
   sleep(3);
 }
```

My structure is like:

```
<table id="listbody">
  <tr>


    <td class="rank">1</td>
        <td class="company"><a href="/companies/icbc/" class="exit_trigger_set">
<img alt="" src="http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/companies/icbc_50x50.jpg">
            <h3>ICBC</h3></a>
        </td>
        <td>China</td>
        <td class="nowrap">$134.8 B</td>
        <td class="nowrap">$37.8 B</td>
        <td class="nowrap">$2,813.5 B</td>
        <td class="nowrap">$237.3 B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
echo $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::className('rank'))->getext();
```

to

```
echo $results[$i]->findElement(WebDriverBy::className('rank'))->getext();
```

Comment: :Thanks a lot sir.Is there any Lynda video tutorial or any other resources where I can really start selenium with php.